# HTML CSS: How do I make Checkbox only Visible when it is Hovered or Selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

How do I make Checkbox only be Visible when:

**1) It is Hovered over**

**2) or Selected**

**3) It is Not visible, when unselected; it only becomes visible when hovered over again**

Ideally prefer not to use JavaScript, only Css-- but if JavaScript is necessary, thats good.
This works only for first time, after I check, but after then unchecked,  I Cannot to see checkbox ever again. It only works once !

**Checkbox html:**

```
<div cardcheckbox id="checkboxdiv">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cardcheckbox" id="checkid" align="right" onclick="toggleBoxVisibility()"/>
</div>
```

**Checkbox css:**

```
.cardcheckbox 
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    visibility: hidden;
}



.card:hover .cardcheckbox         
 {
     visibility: visible;
 }
```

**Checkbox Javascript:**

```
function toggleBoxVisibility() {
    if (document.getElementById("checkid").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("checkid").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
else {
    document.getElementById("checkid").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

**Resource:**

[Changing CSS visibility with JavaScript if a checkbox has been checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743087/changing-css-visibility-with-javascript-if-a-checkbox-has-been-checked)

Comment: So, how can I hover over an invisible checkbox? Or do you mean only show checkbox when hovering over label or parent div?

Comment: no need of using java-script , https://jsfiddle.net/6hu3mL0f/5/

Comment: `visibility: hidden` disables pointer events on the element. As the other answers mentioned, you'll need to use opacity if you want to react to hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    .cardcheckbox {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .cardcheckbox:hover,
    .cardcheckbox:checked {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

This is pure CSS solution for you!

Comment: thanks this is awesome, by the way, is javascript or css the preferable way for coding practice? I also found a javascript way also

Comment: for me, personally, CSS way is better than JS way . It can give you better performance and less headache

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Not an expert. I don't know why the "visbility" value isn't working for you.

Try this:

```
.cardcheckbox 
{
    opacity: 0;
}

.cardcheckbox:hover        
 {
     opacity:1;
 }
```

Comment: I think we cannot click on an 'visibility: hidden;' element (but we can use tab key to focus on this), so opacity is the better way to hide the checkbox on this case