# SASS - Applying style in pseudo element (after) of parent if child element is checked

Tags: css, sass

Basically I have the follow html structure:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <div>
    <label class="custom-control-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="xislo" />
      Xislo
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yes, I'm using bootstrap, but this html is automatic generated, compromising the bootstrap strucutre. Now, I need to make the custom checkbox work again.

The problem is, the pseudo element after of the label can't inherit the :checked state of input element (inside the label).

How can I do  to manipulate after pseudo element of label using SASS in this case?

I'm trying:

```
 .custom-control-label::after .custom-control-input:checked  {
      background-color: $primary;
      background-image: $custom-checkbox-indicator-icon-checked;
 }
```

Comment: You cannot style a parent based on the state of the child in CSS, as there is no parent selector in CSS. What you are attempting to achieve is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a little of javascript in order to achieve this.

Review this answer 
[Changing CSS visibility with JavaScript if a checkbox has been checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743087/changing-css-visibility-with-javascript-if-a-checkbox-has-been-checked)

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Obsidian Age it is impossible to target the parent by just using CSS. I would recommend to create a simple script for this scenario since you are using Bootstrap a little help of JQuery wont be bad. Check out [jquery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).